# Open shadow DOM css style manupulation reactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i am working with AWS cognito and trying to manipulate the components shadow DOM. I am using react and i keep getting the error that it cant read property 'shadowRoot' of null. This is regardless of the host value.

I have a signIn component and this is how i export and try to modify the DOM:

```
export default () => {
    var host = document.getElementById("shadow-root"); // i've also tried the name of the component (with getElementByTagName)
    var style = document.createElement( 'style' )
     style.innerHTML = '* { background:red; }'
     host.shadowRoot.appendChild( style )
    
    return(
        <SignIn/>
    )
};
```

This is the error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of undefined
push../src/userAuthentication/SignUp.js.__webpack_exports__.default
src/userAuthentication/SignUp.js:194
  191 | var host = document.getElementsByTagName("amplify-authenticator")[0];
  192 | var style = document.createElement( 'style' )
  193 |  style.innerHTML = '* { background:red; }'
> 194 |  host.shadowRoot.appendChild( style )
      | ^  195 | 
  196 | return(
  197 |     <SignIn/>
```